TNavButton missing in Delphi 12.0
My application has been working fine on Delphi 10.3. However, it failed to compile when using Delphi 12.0 because of undeclared TNavButton. I did a comparison of a file vcl.DBCtrls.pas between Delphi 10.3 and 12.0 and noticed TNavButton is no longer in Delphi 12.0. Has anyone experienced this issue? Any solution would be appreciated. Thanks.
I copied TNavButton on vcl.DBCtrls.pas in Delphi 10.3 and pasted over to Delphi 12.0, but the error was still there.

Try using the TNavButton that is in the Vcl.Buttons unit.
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Buttons.TNavButton
